# Hibernate: Register custom PostreSQL operators

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I would like to use the [SIMILAR TO](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-similar-operator.php) operator in my HQL queries, but the HQL parser doesn't recognize this operator, since it is specific to PostgreSQL.

Something like this: `FROM Person WHERE name SIMILAR TO :name`.

I want to avoid doing this with native queries.

Is there a way to add support for this operator to Hibernate? I'm looking into extending the `PostgreSQL10Dialect` class, but so far I didn't find a way how to do this.

Comment: That is not possible to introduce new operators, however it is possible to use db functions, for example: `function('textregexeq', name, :name) = true`

Comment: Hmm..., `SIMILAR TO` may work like a function too... `new SQLFunctionTemplate(BooleanType.INSTANCE, "(?1 SIMILAR TO ?2)")`, but again, you will need to call it as a function: `similarto(name,:name)`

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [this forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2431688) and comments from
Andrey B. Panfilov I created the following dialect:

```
public class CustomPostgreSQL10Dialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQL10Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("similarTo", new SQLFunctionTemplate(BooleanType.INSTANCE, "(?1 SIMILAR TO ?2)"));
    }
}
```

Usage: `FROM Person WHERE similarTo(name, :name) = true`